FacetimeHD keeps disappearing - how to make it stick? (Linux on Mac)
FacetimeHD keeps disappearing, usually (but not always) after a reboot. Sometimes, I only notice it till I'm on a call and I can't fire up the video.
My workaround is to launch a script that re-installs it each time I notice that happens.
I'd love a way to make it stick, forever.
Anyone else having the same problem?
